# GUI not running - not finding entry point in DLL

Tags: go, dll, andlabs-ui

I am trying following simple GUI code:

```
package main
import ("github.com/andlabs/ui"; "os")
func main() {
    ui.Main(makeMainWin)
}
func makeMainWin(){
    var mainWindow = ui.NewWindow("MyTitle", 500, 250, false) 
    var mainbox = ui.NewVerticalBox()
    mainbox.Append(ui.NewLabel("A Label"), false)
    var exitButton = ui.NewButton("Exit")
    exitButton.OnClicked( func(*ui.Button){os.Exit(0)} )
    mainbox.Append(exitButton, false)
    mainWindow.SetChild(mainbox)
    mainWindow.OnClosing( func (*ui.Window) bool { ui.Quit(); return true   } )
    mainWindow.Show()
}
```

The code compiles and builds without any error or warning. However, when I try to run it from command line, I get following error:

```
exit status -1073741511
```

On double clicking the built exe file, I get a dialog box with following message:

```
The procedure entry point TaskDialog could not be located 
in the dynamic link library COMCTL32.DLL
```

I ran [CCleaner](https://www.ccleaner.com/) and fixed large number of registry issues but above problem persists.

I am working with following versions on Windows7:

```
go version go1.12.9 windows/386

gcc (i686-posix-dwarf-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a manifest that instructs windows to load common controls. Have you followed the instructions at https://github.com/andlabs/ui/blob/master/README.md, specifically about the winres import?